# How does slicing in three dimensional numpy array work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-slicing

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], [[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]])
print(arr[0:2, : , 2]
```

I know that elements 3, 6, 9 and 12 are selected but can't figure out whether the output is
printed as a one-dimensional array or two dimensional array or more.
How does it work?

Ouput:

[image]

Comment: you can check the dimension`arr[0:2, : , 2].ndim` or shape `arr[0:2, : , 2].shape`

Comment: Hi Sandeep, it would be worth the time to go through this official documentation on [advance indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html). That should give you clarity on why your outputs look like they do.

Comment: Short answer: after indexing numpy automaticaly remove the singleton dimensions (= the axes of length one).

Answer (score 1):

```py
arr = np.array([[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], [[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]])

# array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
#         [ 4,  5,  6]],

#        [[ 7,  8,  9],
#         [10, 11, 12]]])

arr.shape # ------> (2,2,3)
# Think of them as axis
# lets create the first 2 axis of (`2`, ...)

#         |(1)
#         |
#         |
#         |         
#         |---------(0)


# now lets create second 2 axis of (2, `2`, ..)

#            (1,1)
#         |
#         |---(1,0)
#         |
#         |
#         |
#         |         |(0,1)
#         |---------|---(0,0)

# now lets create the last 3 axis of (2, 2, `3`)

#           /``(1,1,0) = 10
#          |-- (1,1,1) = 11
#         | \__(1,1,2) = 12
#         |
#         |  /``(1,0,0) = 7
#         |--|--(1,0,1) = 8
#         |  \__(1,0,2) = 9
#         |
#         |
#         |         /``(0,1,0) = 4
#         |         |--(0,1,1) = 5
#         |         \__(0,1,2) = 6
#         |         |
#         |         |
#         |---------|---/``(0,0,0) = 1
#                       |--(0,0,1) = 2
#                       \__(0,0,2) = 3

# now suppose you ask
arr[0, :, :] # give me the first axis alon with all it's component

#         |
#         |         /``(0,1,0) = 4
#         |         |--(0,1,1) = 5
#         |         \__(0,1,2) = 6
#         |         |
#         |         |
#         |---------|---/``(0,0,0) = 1
#                       |--(0,0,1) = 2
#                       \__(0,0,2) = 3

# So it will print 

# array([[1, 2, 3],
#        [4, 5, 6]])

arr[:, 0, :] # you ask take all the first axis 1ut give me only the first axis of the first axis and all its components

#           
#         
#         
#         
#         |  /``(1,0,0) = 7
#         |--|--(1,0,1) = 8
#         |  \__(1,0,2) = 9
#         |
#         |
#         |         
#         |         
#         |         
#         |         
#         |         
#         |---------|---/``(0,0,0) = 1
#                       |--(0,0,1) = 2
#                       \__(0,0,2) = 3

# so you get the output

# array([[1, 2, 3],
#        [7, 8, 9]])

# like wise you ask
print(arr[0:2, : , 2])
# so you are saying give (0,1) first axis, all of its children and only 3rd (index starts at 0 so 2 means 3) children
# 0:2 means 0 to 2 `excluding` 2; 0:5 means 0,1,2,3,4

#           
#          |
#         | \__(1,1,2) = 12
#         |
#         |  
#         |--
#         |  \__(1,0,2) = 9
#         |
#         |
#         |        
#         |         
#         |         \__(0,1,2) = 6
#         |         |
#         |         |
#         |---------|---/
#                       |
#                       \__(0,0,2) = 3

# so you get

# array([[ 3,  6],
#        [ 9, 12]])
```

Answer (score 1):

## Going In

Given the array:

```
    arr = np.array([[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], [[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]])
```

The shape of arr, given by `arr.shape` is `(2,2,3)`.

That basically means that if we start from outside (and ignore the first square bracket), we have 2 arrays in that scope. If we enter to one of those we can count 2 arrays and if we enter either we find 3 elements. I think having this view is quite helpful in understanding the following.

Specifying `arr[1,1,2]` selects the second array(index 1) in the outermost scope, and *then* selects the second array in the following scope and *then* selects the third element.  The output is a single number:

```
    12
```

specifying `arr[:,1,2]` first simultaneously selects all arrays at the outermost scope and *then* for each of these selects the second array (index 1). When we *then* enter into the next scope, we pick out the 3rd elements. This outputs two numbers:

```
    array([ 6, 12])
```

specifying arr[:, : , 2] outputs 4 numbers since
1. at the first scope we selected all arrays (2)
2. at the next scope we selected all array (2 for each in the first)

```
    array([[ 3,  6],
           [ 9, 12]])
```

## Coming out

Instinctually, the reason why they appear as 2x2 array can be viewed as receding from the lowermost scope. Elements are getting enclosed in square brackets because that share a scope. 3 and 6 will be in one array while 9 and 12 will be in another array.

Answer (score 0):

To check the shape of an array, just run the .shape method:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], [[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]])
print(arr[0:2, : , 2].shape)
```

Output: (2, 2)

So you've got a 2 x 2 array.

Hope that's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Numpy N-Dimensional Array/List
Basically when using normal list slicing

**Normal List**

```
start,end=0,5
l=[1,2,3,4,5]
print(l[start:end])

[1,2,3,4,5]
```

**Numpy Array ([List[list[list..]]])**

So here when we refer the given numpy array
arr=[[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], [[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]]

**Level 0** splices the **base Elems**

```
arr[0:]  [[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], [[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]]
arr[1:]  [[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
```

**Level 1** splices the **child** of **base Elems**

```
arr[0:,1:] [[[4,5,6]],[[10,11,12]]]
```

**Level 2** splices the **subchilds** of **child Elems**

```
arr[0:,1:,1:] [[[5,6]],[[11,12]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Indexing/slicing a 3d array is really no different than doing the same on a 1d, 2d, or 20d.

```
In [580]: arr
Out[580]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6]],

       [[ 7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12]]])
In [581]: arr[:,:,2]
Out[581]: 
array([[ 3,  6],
       [ 9, 12]])
```

For a (2,2,3) shape, slicing with `0:2` is the same as `:`, the whole dimension.  So your example just selects the "2" subarray along the last axis.  Indexing with a scalar reduces that dimension, so the (2,2,3) => (2,2).

Look where the result values are in the original - the right most column, but split across 2 planes.  2 high column in 2 plane results in a (2,2) array.

`numpy` has a flexible multidimensional array layout, and corresponding indexing system.  That means `arr[:,1,:]` and `arr[1,:,:]` and even `arr[1,:,2]` all work the same way, though the results differ.  But the underlying mechanism is basically the same.

```
In [582]: arr[1,:,:]
Out[582]: 
array([[ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]])
In [583]: arr[1,:,2]
Out[583]: array([ 9, 12])
In [585]: arr[:,1,2]
Out[585]: array([ 6, 12])
```